# LOAD CSV with unwound arrays fails to do...anything

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have a CSV file of ~9,000 rows of employee data.   It contains a column called "DeclaredTags" that contains a list of tags in a single string, for example `"foo; bar; baz; quux"`.  The average person has less than 10, some people have none.

All of the people are already loaded into the database.  I'm using the following statement to load just the tags:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:/path_to/people_26Nov14.csv'
AS l
MATCH (p:Person { empid: l.EmployeeNumber })
WHERE l.DeclaredTags <> ""
WITH l, split(l.DeclaredTags, "; ") AS tags, p
UNWIND tags as tag
MERGE (t:Tag {label: tag})
MERGE (p)-[:tagged]->(t);
```

This query simply churns forever; periodically I try to do counts of the number of tags created, and it's always 0.  (I.e. `MATCH (t:Tag) return count(t)`).

What's going on here?  Is it something with my use of `split` and `UNWIND`?

What's the better way to formulate splitting arrays inside of columns into individual values, all linked back to the same node?

**EDIT** - I have recently cut down my data sample to only 24 rows, just to figure if I'm not being patient enough.   After about 10 minutes of runtime, the query is still hanging.

**EDIT 2** - The issue seems to be with the MERGE that creates the relationship. If I just return the data from the CSV (creating nothing) it works.  If I only create the `:Tag` node (without the relationship from `(p)-[:tagged]->(t)`), then it works. It's only with that last relationship merge that the query hangs.

Comment: Possibly silly question, is the space matching, or should it be `"\\s+`?

Comment: I think so, it's hard to prove.  But in any case, even if it wasn't matching, you'd expect multiple tags to all go into the same string.  Then I'd have tags with labels like "foo; bar" if it wasn't matching.  Except I don't even have that much.

Comment: do you have indexes for `:Person(empid)` and `:Tag(label)` ?

Comment: can you share those 24 lines of data? Please also read my [blog posts](http://jexp.de/blog/?s=load%20csv), and check your csv data with csvkit.

Comment: On `:Person(empid)` I've tried it both ways, with and without.  On `:Tag(Label)` no.

Comment: I'll check the blog posts and double check the CSV.  I can't share the CSV without some significant modifications (and then re-testing to make sure the issue persists).  I'm working towards that now, to verify and re-verify that it's an issue under different scenarios.

Comment: I'd separate creating the nodes and the rels, otherwise you might run into the Eager pipe problem that I described in the second blog post (and Mark Needhaam too) www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried FOREACH?

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:/path_to/people_26Nov14.csv'
AS l WITH l
WHERE l.DeclaredTags <> ""
MATCH (p:Person { empid: l.EmployeeNumber })
FOREACH(tag IN SPLIT(l.DeclaredTags, '; ') |
    MERGE (t:Tag {label: tag})
    MERGE (p)-[:tagged]->(t)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea, I hadn't considered it.  It seems to have the same problem though.  I tried this query approach, cut down the data sample to a mere 24 rows, and still the `LOAD CSV` simply hangs.  Several minutes later, counting nodes with `:Tag` is still zero.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the MERGE that creates the relationship.  If I just return the data from the CSV it works.  If I only create the `Tag` node (without the relationship from (p)-[:tagged]->(t), then it works.  It's only with that last relationship merge that the query hangs.

Comment: I tested this on a .csv I simulated with 100 rows. First I created all 100 employees, then ran this LOAD CSV query. It didn't hang. How many employees are already in your db? Is each row in your .csv file a unique employee?

Comment: Yes, each line is a unique employee.  About 8,800 employees - each with ~12 properties, and existing relationships to about 5 other node types (things like organizational group).

Comment: If it's possible this is actually a neo4j bug I can fake a sample of my data and try to post it for replication.  I'm running on 2.1.2

Comment: You should send me a sample so I can try to replicate the hang.

Comment: I will try to follow up later.  I've just upgraded to 2.1.6 to see if it makes a difference, and I'm re-importing everything in a fresh DB to make sure *I* can replicate before I fake up the sample.